# MySQL запрос из трёх таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть три таблицы: `Table1` (`id`, `code`, `vendor`), `Table2` (`id`, `price`, `color`, `code`) и `Table3` (`id`, `price`, `color`, `code`). `Table2` - таблица X типа товара выпускаемый vendor. `Table3` - таблица Y типа товара.

Нужно найти производителя `vendor` из `Table1`, который выпускает минимум три товара из `Table2` и `Table3`.

Дошел до такого запроса:

```
SELECT vendor
FROM Table1,Table2,Table3
WHERE Table1.code = Table2.code AND Table1.code = Table3.code
GROUP BY vendor
HAVING COUNT(Table2.code) >3 AND COUNT(Table3.code) >3;
```

Но он работает не корректно.

Comment: Если нужно, то найдите! В чем вопрос, что у вас не получается?

Comment: Подскажите правильный запрос.

Comment: Предлагаете сделать работу за вас?

Comment: Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода, структуру таблиц и пр

Comment: Как вы представляете написание запроса без точной структуры всех 3х таблиц, иноформации о связях этих таблиц. И еще желательны образцы данных

Comment: посмотрите сюда, можете тестовые данные поправить. глядишь, вам и помогут  - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c297c1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел ваш запрос и кажется понял, что вы хотели получить. Проблема в вашем запросе в том, что `count()` от любого поля в БД дает количество строк в выборке, в которых это поле НЕ NULL. А когда вы переклеиваете таблицу 2 и 3 по коду вендора на выходе вы получаете перемноженные наборы. Если в таблице 2 по вендору1 три записи, а в таблице 3 две записи - то в результирующем наборе будут все варианты расстановок т.е. 2*3=6 записей и оба `count()` вернут значение 6.

Вам видимо надо посчитать отдельно количество записей во 2й и 3й таблицах. Проще всего сделать это отдельными подзапросами, каждый из которых вернет коды тех вендоров у которых более 3х записей. После чего объединить списки кодов и на выходе получатся записи с кодами, которые были выданы обоими подзапросами:

```
SELECT vendor
  FROM Table1,
       (select code from Table2 group by code having count(1)>3) A,
       (select code from Table3 group by code having count(1)>3) B
 WHERE Table1.code = A.code AND Table1.code = B.code
```

Comment: Спасибо приятель. 
Живи долго и процветай.

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса мало что понятно. Вот на быструю руку написал так как понял, извините если что-то не так, уточняйте лучше.

```
SELECT t1.vendor FROM Tabl1 t1, Tabl2 t2, Tabl3 t3 WHERE t1.id = t2.vendorid
AND t1.id = t3.vendorid GROUP BY t1.id HAVING COUNT(t1.id) > 3
```